# What commands will make tool display?

Tags: makefile

The following is a previous exam question which I lost quite a few marks on, and I'm still not sure why.

Lets say I have a directory containing the following files:

```
fileB.txt  makefile  scriptC  programA.h  programA.c
```

And a *makefile* whose contents are as follows :

```
fileE.txt: fileD.txt programA
      programA fileD.txt >| fileE.txt
 programA.o: programA.h programA.c
      gcc -c -Wall programA.c
 programA: programA.o
      gcc -o programA programA.o
 fileD.txt: fileB.txt scriptC
      scriptC fileB.txt >| fileD.txt
 CC=gcc
 CFLAGS=-Wall
```

a) The first time you type make in the command prompt, what commands will the make tool display and execute?

b) Now lets say you update, or *touch*, fileB.txt, what commands will the make tool display then?

I can't replicate the program to try it myself, since I don't actually know what the program is doing. I can predict the output of simple make files, but I've never seen one like the one below, i.e using pipes and txt files. A simple explanation concerning the problem would be very helpful.

Comment: The *contents* of the rules don't matter you can fake those however you like to test this. Stick `echo` in front of each line and how the makefile proceeds doesn't change (though you would also need to touch the output file if you wanted to be closer to duplicating the effect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fileE.txt: fileD.txt programA
     programA fileD.txt >| fileE.txt
programA.o: programA.h programA.c
     gcc -c -Wall programA.c
programA: programA.o
     gcc -o programA programA.o
fileD.txt: fileB.txt scriptC
     scriptC fileB.txt >| fileD.txt
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
```

Let's try this live/blind.

1. The [default goal/target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals) for this makefile is `fileE.txt` so that's what `make` will try to build by default
2. `fileE.txt` depends on `fileD.txt` and `programA`
3. make will then see if `fileD.txt` exists (it doesn't) so it will try to create it
4. `fileD.txt` depends on `fileB.txt` and `scriptC`
5. Both of those exist already so make will run the rule for `fileD.txt`

   - Output: `scriptC fileB.txt >| fileD.txt`
6. It doesn't matter what `scriptC` does here because `fileD.txt` is created by the shell redirection
7. `fileD.txt` is now up to date and make moves on to `programA`
8. `programA` does not exist so make tries to build it
9. `programA` depends on `programA.o` which doesn't exist so make tries to build it
10. `programA.o` depends on `programA.h` and `programA.c`
11. Both of those exist so make will run the rule for `programA.o`

    - Output: `gcc -c -Wall programA.c`
12. gcc creates `programA.o`
13. `programA.o` is now up to date so make moves on
14. All of `programA`'s prerequisites are now built so make runs the rule for it

    - Output: `gcc -o programA programA.o`
15. All the prerequisites of `fileE.txt` are now up to date so make runs the rule for it

    - Output: `programA fileD.txt >| fileE.txt`
16. make is done

Summing up just the output from the above steps you get:

```
scriptC fileB.txt >| fileD.txt
gcc -c -Wall programA.c
gcc -o programA programA.o
programA fileD.txt >| fileE.txt
```

Now if you `touch fileB.txt` at this point and run `make again you get:

1. The [default goal/target](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals) for this makefile is `fileE.txt` so that's what `make` will try to build by default
2. `fileE.txt` depends on `fileD.txt` and `programA`
3. make will then see if `fileD.txt` exists (it does) and will check its prerequisites
4. `fileB.txt` is newer than `fileD.txt` so make will mark `fileD.txt` as needing to be rebuilt
5. `scriptC` is older than `fileD.txt` but that doesn't change anything
6. The prerequisites of `fileD.txt` are now finished and `fileD.txt` needs to be rebuilt

   - Output: `scriptC fileB.txt >| fileD.txt`
7. `fileD.txt` is now up to date so make moves on
8. `programA` is older than `fileE.txt` (and is itself up to date) so make moves on
9. All the prerequisites of `fileE.txt` are now up to date and some were built and are now newer so make will run the rule to build `fileE.txt`

   - Output: `programA fileD.txt >| fileE.txt`

Summing up just the output from the above steps you get:

```
scriptC fileB.txt >| fileD.txt
programA fileD.txt >| fileE.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following reasoning/rules:

1. Just follow the targets dependencies
2. If a dependency is not present it gets build (or if there is not target for it, an error occurs)
3. If a timestamp of the dependency is newer, the target gets (re)build.
4. The first target encoutered in your Makefile is executed (if no targets are given by the make command)

So assuming no targets are given rule 4 is used and `fileE.txt` is the 'active' target.

`fileE.txt` requires that `fileD.txt` and `programA` are available (rule 1). Both are not available, so they need to be build (rule 2).

`fileD.txt` requires that `fileB.txt` and `scriptC` are available (rule 1). No targets for these dependencies are defined, so they do not get rebuild. And `fileD.txt` can be build  (rule 2).

`programA` requires that `programA.o` is available  (rule 1). A target is provided so `programA.o` can be build (rule 2). Next, `programA` can be build  (rule 2).

Now all requirements for `fileE.txt` are met, so it can be build as well.

Same goes when `fileB.txt` gets touched, but you need to apply rule 3 as well.

Using this (partial) example and information you should be able to determine which commands are executed (and on which order).

Answer (score 1):

a) The first time you type make in the command prompt, what commands will the make tool display and execute?

1. At first the first target in the `makefile` is executed. Here it is `fileE.txt`
2. Since `fileE.txt` depends on `fileD.txt and programA` these will be your target now.
3. Similarly based on your target and dependencies the final target is obtained.

Below is the sequence in which the commands are executed. Comments inline

> 1. **scriptC fileB.txt >| fileD.txt**  /* ouput is fileD.txt*/
> 2. **gcc -c -Wall programA.c**         /*ouput is programA.o needed by programA*/
> 3. **gcc -o programA programA.o** /*ouput is programA needed by fileE.txt*/
> 4. **programA fileD.txt >| fileE.txt** /*the final output file fileE.txt*/

b) Now lets say you update, or touch, fileB.txt, what commands will the make tool display then?
Following commands are executed.

> 1. **scriptC fileB.txt >| fileD.txt**  /* ouput is fileD.txt*/
> 2. **programA fileD.txt >| fileE.txt** /*the final output file fileE.txt*/

In this case, `programA` is not rebuilt as it already available.